# Prestashop, PHP, cannot create and save plain text file

Tags: php, prestashop

OK. I am very confused with Prestashop. My code looks like this:

```
private static function _saveToFile($vouchers = array())
{
    $file = fopen(__DIR__ . 'codes.txt', 'a');

    foreach ($vouchers as $voucher)
    {
        fwrite($file, $voucher->code . "\r\n");
    }

    fclose($file);
}
```

And is being called like that:

```
Voucher::_saveToFile($vouchers);
```

I see a trivial fopen, fwrite, fclose situation but the file is nowhere to be found on the server. I tried `fopen(__DIR__ . 'codes.txt', 'a')`, `fopen('codes.txt', 'a')`. I set flags to `'w'` and `'a'`. Everything produces the same outcome: no file at all.

I am certain that program gets to this code because when I do `d($file)` before `fopen()ing` it will die and show me that $file has resource object.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Is `error_reporting` `E_ALL` and `display_errors` set to `true`? This might be a security issue, apply the right level of rights to the PHP user. Also print the full path before applying it in fopen and `print/echo` it, to make sure its correct.

Comment: I have Prestashop debugging enabled: no warning and no errors were shown. Though it might be something to look into.

Comment: My guess is that the path is missing a slash `/`

Comment: Exactly. I found it the very same moment. When trying to find a file I noticed one called 'classescodes.txt'. I facepalmed. Hour wasted on something that could've been resolved by drinking coffee before working. :) Could you type it as an answer so I could mark it? :)

Comment: Oh sorry I just post it in the answers xD Thank you ^^ I was drinking coffee, I guess that's why then..

Comment: use _PS_ROOT_DIR_ when dealing with prestashop inside prestashop classes or module files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually pretty certain that the path is missing a slash between `__DIR__` and 'codes.txt'

Comment: Would be nice if you could expand a bit on why that solution works, and the nature of the problem. Just for the sake of others who'll come across this question in the future. Like possibly a link to PHP docs (http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) about magic constants, and where it clearly indicates that __DIR__ does NOT return with a trailing slash. Better yet would be some advice like @Abdulla Chozhimadathil suggets about using the Prestashop specific PS_ROOT_DIR constant.